# Is it possible to store data within a key, within another key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key, storage

I have an dictionary of keys that are the initials of employees' names. I need to store data for each month of the year, for each employee (key). Is it possible to store each month as a key, within each employee key, and then store data for each month?

This is my code if it helps:

```
#Creates dictionary, each employee as a key
employee_dict = dict((z[0],list(z[1:])) for z in zip(employee_list))

for key, value in employee_dict.items():
    for i in data_to_store_for_each_employee_array:
        if i[0] == key:
            employee_dict[key].append(i[1])
```

My programs reads the employee initials off of a txt file using configparser. It then stores the employee initials into a list. The initials are prone to change so I am unable to hard-code them into my program

My dictionary looks like this right now:

```
dict_items([('TS', []), ('IR', []), ('RD', []), ('SP', []), ('RA', []), ('WN', []), ('KT', [])])

I was hoping to get it to look something like:
dict_items([('TS': January[], February[], March[]....) {and so on, for each pair of initials}
```

Comment: Can you include a small example of how the dictionary currently looks, and how you expect it to look?

Comment: Yes, you can have any level of nesting you want {'employee_name':{'month-year-key': data-you-want-to-store}}

Comment: Is it possible to create this for each employee in the txt file using a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a dictionary with a each having a dictionary value (a nested dictionary). This is what it would look like:

```
info_dict = {
    'employee_1': {'January': #data, 
        'February':#data}
    'employee_2': {'January': #data, 
        'February':#data}
    'employee_3': {'January': #data, 
        'February':#data}
    }
```

If you have a .txt file of employee names than you would turn those into  keys and add the value to a particular employee key:

```
employees = []
dictionary = {}
nested_dictionary = {}

filename = '#file_name'
with open(filename, 'r') as f_obj:
   lines = f_obj.readlines()
   for line in lines:
      name_lst = line.split(' ')
      for name in name_lst:
          employees.append(name)
    
for employee in employees:
   dictionary[employee] = None #Because I don't know where you're data is coming from...

print(dictionary)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have a .txt file where the employees are listed (the employees are prone to change so I cannot hard code the employees into the program). Using configparser, I store the employee names into a list in Python. As for the data I need to store, I am scanning an excel document using OpenPyxl.

Comment: I edited my response to allow you gather employee names from a .txt file. This is a tutorial article which I think will help you with the OpenPyxl part: https://realpython.com/openpyxl-excel-spreadsheets-python/ . I hope this helps you to get started.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am able to read off the .txt file and store the employee initials into a list in python and I have implemented this in my program. Is it possible to create a for loop that creates a nested dictionary for each employee to store each initials as a key, with each month as another key within the first one, and then data for each month?

Comment: Yes it is possible but you would have to use many `for` loops because your looping through multiple dictionaries.